# Removing index duplicates in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

There is a some seemingly inconsistent behaviour observed when removing duplicates in pandas.

**Problem set up**: I have a dataframe with three columns and 3330 timeseries observations as shown below:

```
data.describe()
       Mean    Buy  Sell
count  3330    3330  3330
```

Checking if the data contains any duplicates, shows there are duplicate indices.

```
data.index.duplicated().any()
True
```

How many duplicates are in the data

```
data.loc[data.index.duplicated()].count()
Mean    38
Buy     38
Sell    38
```

The duplicates can be visually inspected too

```
 `data[data.index.duplicated()]`
```

**Dilemma**: Clearly, there are duplicates in the data and it seems they are 38 of them per column. However, when I use the DataFrame's drop_duplicates(), it seems more data is dropped than expected.

```
`data.drop_duplicates().count()`
Mean    3241
Buy     3241
Sell    3241
dtype: int64
```

```
`data.count() - data.drop_duplicates().count()` 
Mean    89
Buy     89
Sell    89
```

Any ideas on what is the cause of this disparity or the detail I'm missing would be appreciated. Note: It is possible to have similar entries of data but dates should not be duplicated hence the reasonable way to clean the data is to remove the duplicate days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep only the first occurrence (row / record) where there are duplicates in your index?

This will accomplish that.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDX':[1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6], 
                 'Mean':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}).set_index('IDX')
df
     Mean
IDX      
1       1
2       2
2       3
2       4
3       5
4       6
5       7
5       8
6       9
duplicates = df.index.duplicated()
duplicates
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False])
keep = duplicates == False
df.loc[keep,:]
     Mean
IDX      
1       1
2       2
3       5
4       6
5       7
6       9
```

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was aiming for. It seems as pointed out, my expectation of df.drop_duplicates() was that it drops based on the index not the data, quite the opposite.

Comment: Perhaps an update on that function would be convenient, allowing the setting of a flag to indicate drop based on index, otherwise how it operates currently could lead to unwanted loss of observations.